# Jenkins trying to configure JDK and Maven with Manage Jenkins, but I do not see those sections and "Global Tool Configuration" in the page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins trying to configure JDK and Maven with Manage Jenkins, but I do not see those sections and "Global Tool Configuration" in the page

I have gone through some document for this issue everyone is saying to use `global tool configuration` but even this option is also not visible in my Jenkin.

Comment: i have gone through some document for this issue everyone is saying to use "global tool configuration" but even this option is also not visible in my jenkin

Comment: Try `<jenkinsURL>/configureTools/`, otherwise its under `global configuration` - `global tool configuration` (so, from `<jenkinURL>/manage`), 4th button, in my case

Comment: thank you it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed solution

> `<jenkinsURL>/configureTools/`,

otherwise its under global `configuration` - `global tool configuration` 
(so, from `<jenkinURL>/manage`), 4th button